# Customizing List of Figure

Tags: table-of-contents, thesis

I need to format the LoF for my thesis write-up in this format; (LoF title with 14pt font size and list entries in regular 13pt font size) [image]
My code is;

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,allcolors=black}

\usepackage{tocloft}

% Center ToC heading
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\bfseries\LARGE}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}

\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % for chapters
% Make \chapter leaders bold
\let\oldcftchapleader\cftchapleader
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\bfseries\oldcftchapleader}


\usepackage{datetime}

\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

% Title Page
\title{MS Thesis}
\author{Salman}
\date{\today --- \currenttime}

\begin{document}
%\maketitle

\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{plain}
\setcounter{page}{9}

\begin{normalsize}

    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
%   \ifx\totalfigures
    \listoffigures
%   \fi

\end{normalsize}

%\listoftables
\ifx\totaltables
    \listoftables
\fi

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{fancyhf}
\begin{normalsize}
\chapter{Introduction}\label{chap_1}
\include{chap_1}

\chapter{Background Theory and Literature Review}\label{chap_2}
\include{chap_2}
\end{normalsize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not completely sure what you want (13pt is not a one of the standard sizes, ask a separate question about that) but try this (less any typos):

```
\documentclass[12,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES} % uppercase title
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\large\bfseries} % bold 14pt
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\par\protect\mbox{}\protect\hrulefill\par} % horizontal line 
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0pt} % left aligned fig entries
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Fig } % put before the number
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{1.5em} % extra space for \cftpresnum

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\chapter{A Chapter}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\centering FIGURE
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}
\centering ANOTHER FIGURE
\caption{Another figure}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Read the manual (`> texdoc tocloft`) for detailed information.

Comment: I am getting **\cftpresnum undefined. \renewcommand{\cftpresnum}**. I have checked the manual too. It has no such text *\cftpresnum*
Also how can I remove the distance between the LoF title and the first list item i.e. Fig 1.1?

Comment: dnt know how but got the desired results with 
`\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\bfseries\Large}
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0pt} % left aligned fig entries
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Fig } % put before the number \addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{1.5em} % extra space for \cftpresnum \renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\newline\rule{\textwidth}{1.5pt}\vspace{-2.5em}} \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\uppercase{List of Figures}\vspace{-0.75em}} \setlength\cftafterloftitleskip{0pt}`

Comment: @SalmanKhan One of my typos. It should have been `\cftfigpresnum`. Fixed with my apologies.

Comment: @SalmanKhan Do you want to turn your second comment into an answer?

Comment: Yes that solved my problem